In version catalog libs I get false errors you can only call the 'from' method a single time
I am tried to use version catalogue with Android-Studio Iguana 2023.2.1 Patch 2.
When I try to Sync Gradle I get this error:
Invalid catalog definition:
 - Problem: In version catalog libs, you can only call the 'from' method a single time.

But I am only using it once, at least from what I understand.
This is my settings.gradle.file
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google {
            content {
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.android.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.google.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("androidx.*")
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    versionCatalogs {
        libs {
            from(files("gradle/libs.versions.toml"))
        }
    }
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "Emvoliasmoi"
include ':app', ':jsch-0.1.55', ':scan'

and this is my libs.version:
[versions]
kotlin="1.9.24"
realm="1.16.0"
androidApplication = "7.3.0"
appCompat = "1.1.0"
constraintLayout="2.1.4"
lifecycle = "2.3.1"
material = "1.11.0"
retrofit = "2.9.0"
gson="2.8.6"
work = "2.3.4"


[libraries]
appCompat = "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appCompat"
constraintLayout = "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$constraintLayout"
lifecycleViewmodel = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle"
lifecycleLivedata = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$lifecycle"
lifecycleCommonJava8 = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle"
material = "com.google.android.material:material:$material"
retrofit = "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit"
converter-gson = "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit"
workRuntime = "androidx.work:work-runtime:$work"


[plugins]
androidApplication = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "androidApplication" }
kotlinAndroid = {id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref="kotlin"}
realm = {id ="id.realm.kotlin", version.ref="realm"}

The path "gradle/libs.versions.toml" is correct relative to settings.gradle file.
An "from" is used only once.
Does any one knows what's wrong here?

Why must you declare this libs.versions.toml file as a version catalog? As per the documentation: Gradle offers a conventional file to declare a catalog. If a libs.versions.toml file is found in the gradle subdirectory of the root build, then a catalog will be automatically declared with the contents of this file.

@Jay you are right. I resolved the error. Post it as an answer so I can accept it as correct answer.

There is no need to specifically declare the default libs.versions.toml in versionCatalogs as it would be picked by the gradle build from the gradle subdirectory, as stated in the documentation:

Gradle offers a conventional file to declare a catalog. If a libs.versions.toml file is found in the gradle subdirectory of the root build, then a catalog will be automatically declared with the contents of this file.


libs is used as default versionCatalog. There is no need to configure.
if you want to add a new catalog, you can do like this:
versionCatalogs {
    androidx {
        from(files("gradle/libs.androidx.toml"))
    }
}


comment this part of the code
//  versionCatalogs {
//        libs {
//           from(files("gradle/libs.versions.toml"))
//       }
//    }

